# How do I print $2 BEFORE $1 from a bash script run by npm?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, npm

so i’m confused about the relationship between my custom npm scripts and the bash scripts they run. 
*EDIT*: i don’t think this an isolated bash issue. i can produce the expected behavior described below by writing `echo $2 $1` into an .sh file and running it directly from the terminal

for example

```
"scripts": {"report":"echo $2 $1"}
```

if i run it from the terminal: `npm run report "first" "second"` 
because in my npm script, i call `$2` ​*BEFORE*​ `$1`, i expect it to output this: `second first`, 
but for some reason it always prints `$1` first: `first second`(edited)

i tried a workaround by caching my arguments as variables and then print those:

```
"scripts": {"report": "(FIRST=$1 && SECOND=$2) && echo $SECOND $FIRST"}
```

but same output: `npm run report "first" "second"` => `first second`

what gives?

Comment: I added possible workaround. See if it fits you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following bash file works good for me:

```
echo $2 $1
```

Run with:

```
bash file.sh 1 2
```

Output:

```
2 1
```

EDIT*:

The problem is with the way you try to use node. It seems the $X variables are not populated by node. It just appends your arguments to the rest of your command.

EDIT*2:

workaround

```
{
"scripts": {"report":"a(){ echo $2 $1; };a"}
}
```

Comment: Terrific, that's exactly the problem. Thank you. I don't understand how the function wrapper helps, but I can confirm that it works!

Comment: Hey, mark the answer as accepted when you can. It gives reputation and removes the question from the list and so on...

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It was what I was looking for. I was trying to force add an argument after $* and the argument was always coming first. I thank you ever so much for the answer as it is clearly not obvious.